# How to import Wordpress posts via JSON link

Tags: json, wordpress, post, import

Scenario breakdown:

I have one site that has a custom post type of portfolio with videos, I'd like to automatically import them into my other site as posts. Using two different themes.
I have the JSON API plugin installed on the main site but would like to know how to import that data into my other site. RSS didn't work, I already tried that, and I can't find a plugin that imports JSON.

I've come across this response before: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102277/import-json-feed-to-wordpress But none of it goes over how to take portions of the JSON and put it into specific variables of the regular post type.

Any help would be awesome! :)

Comment: have you tried this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/